# What do you call it when you write the next word in a sequence twice instead of the current and next word?

Tags: terminology

I'm not sure how to phrase it, but I'll give an example.
Let's say I want to type "Think this will be the last instruction?"

While typing this out, I recite the phrase in my head, but I type the following:
"this this will be the last instruction?"

Instead of writing "Think this", I mentally skipped the word I was supposed to write and instead wrote the next word in the sequence twice.

Is there a word for this, or is this some form of dyslexia?

Comment: It's a common and quite natural phenomenon, it's one of the most frequent writing mistakes, for example there are many instances of that in the Old Novgorod [birch-bark letters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birch_bark_manuscript#East_Slavic_texts), 9th to 15th century CE, where a following, anticipated letter is written instead of the current one.

Comment: I don't know about accidentally duplicating a word, but intentionally duplicating it is called https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduplication and is a way of creating emphasis.

Comment: "Dittography" is a word for accidental word duplication. It is  used by textual scholars.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is called an *anticipation error*, where your planning for the next word interfered with your planning for the current word.

The opposite is a *perseveration error*, where your planning for the *previous* word interfered with your planning for the current word.

Comment: In my experience, this tends to happen mostly when the words are similar. As in the example, where both words start with "thi".

Comment: @Barmar: It is also more likely to survive the editing process if it's a short word and/or a function word, like "the," because the reader may mentally correct such errors without even noticing them.

Comment: @Kevin Or like the old puzzle with a sentence in a triange, where "the" is repeated across line breaks.